# Changed embedded tomcat server version to 9 and using spring boot 1.5.10 RELEASE getting able to start embed web application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, tomcat

We are using spring boot 1.5.10 release and default embedded tomcat server 8.4.5 and changed the tomcat server to 9.0.3 by using
Gradle 2.12 version in build.gradle
ext('tomcat.version:9.0.3')

and trying to run apllication Getting Error: .... nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.catalina.Context.addServletMapping(Ljava/lang/String)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Spring Boot 1.5 [does not support using Tomcat 9 as an embedded web server](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.x/reference/htmlsingle/#_servlet_containers). To use Tomcat 9 you should upgrade to a supported version of Spring Boot. At the time of writing, 2.5.x and 2.6.x are the supported versions. Both use Tomcat 9.0.x by default.